# Attributes on C#9 top level statements file

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

I'm trying to add attributes to a top-level statements file, and I'm not finding anything about it. Is it possible?

For some context: I want to disable a rule only in that file with:

```
[SuppressMessage("StyleCop.CSharp.LayoutRules", "SA1516:ElementsMustBeSeparatedByBlankLine", Justification = "Reviewed.")]
```

It's a rule with a known bug in top-level statements.

Is there any way?

Comment: ...or are you wanting to add the attribute to the anonymous method represented by the top-level scope?

Comment: I want to add that to only the Program class/file. I'm not sure how top level statements work under the hood, but I suppose a Program class is generated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a similar issue with the `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]` attribute I wanted to use and received an answer for C# 10 that works. So if you able to migrate to C# 10 you can do the following with a `partial class`:

Create a `Program.Attributes.cs` (I named it that way, so it is nested under the `Program.cs`) with the following code:

```
[SuppressMessage("StyleCop.CSharp.LayoutRules", "SA1516:ElementsMustBeSeparatedByBlankLine", Justification = "Reviewed.")]
public static partial class Program { }
```

See the original answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72013001/1099519

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to set an assembly-wide attribute, then it's the same as it was before C# 9.0. You're missing the `assembly:` keyword.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/set-attributes

Change your code to add the `assembly:` keyword, like so:

```cs
[assembly: SuppressMessage("StyleCop.CSharp.LayoutRules", "SA1516:ElementsMustBeSeparatedByBlankLine", Justification = "Reviewed.")
```

---

If you want to add the attribute to the implicit entrypoint method (aka `Program.Main`) or its parent type `class Program` then **you cannot**, simply because C# 9.0's top-level-statements design does not allow programs to name or reference the method at all.

This is mentioned, briefly, in the documentation on top-level methods (emphasis mine):

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements#implicit-entry-point-method
>
> #### Implicit entry point method
>
> The compiler generates a method to serve as the program entry point for a project with top-level statements. The name of this method isn't actually Main, it's an implementation detail **that your code can't reference directly.** The signature of the method depends on whether the top-level statements contain the `await` keyword or the `return` statement.

...in which case you'll need to change your code back to using a traditional explicit `Main` method:

```
[SuppressMessage("SomeClassRule", "", Justification = "It's my computer")]
public static class Program
{
    [SuppressMessage("SomeMethodRule", "", Justification = "It's my computer")]
    public static async Task<Int32> Main( String[] args )
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

---

**However...**, as you're wanting to use `[SuppressMessage]` on the `Main` method to suppress StyleCop warnings, you need to be made-aware of the fact that StyleCop (as with other static-analysis tools in .NET) now respect `.editorconfig` and `#pragma warning disable|restore` to suppress or disable warnings and checks.

Here's a quick comparison of `#pragma` vs `[SuppressMessage]`: when a technique has a "better" feature it's marked in **bold**:

|  | `#pragma warning disable` | `[SuppressMessage]` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Compiled into output assembly, growing your DLL size from all the constant strings and potentially exposing internal development details to external users | **No** | Yes |
| Explicit `Justification` field | No But you can add an explanatory comment on the same line. | **Yes** |
| Explicit target field for disambiguation | No | **Yes** |
| Requires modern versions of Visual Studio (2017 or 2019+) | Yes | **No** |
| Granularity | Source code line But if the same warning appears 2 or more times on the same source code line you cannot disambiguate | Discrete .NET assembly objects (types, parameters, fields, etc - but not per-line) |

Comment: Wouldn't that affect all of the project files? I want it to affect only the "Program" class/file

Comment: @Iván I've expanded my answer.

Comment: Ok, then I'll have to wait until StyleCop fixes top-level statement inteactions. Thanks!

Comment: @Iván Is there a reason you can't use `.editorconfig` or `#pragma` instead? The `SuppressMessage` attribute is long out of fashion. I haven't needed to use it in years...

Comment: It's just what StyleCop says in the doc. I'll try with pragma, but I can't find any doc about it

Comment: @Iván I think you're using the _legacy_ StyleCop, because the Roslyn-integrated StyleCop uses `#pragma`: https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/issues/2278  - for example the `SA1516:ElementsMustBeSeparatedByBlankLine` rule uses `#pragma warning disable SA1516` (see https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1516.md )

Comment: I was reading: https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1516.md And I'm seeing now the pragma snippet at the end, my bad. Thanks!