# C# 9/10 top-level statements and ExcludeFromCodeCoverage-Attribute?

Tags: c#, code-coverage, c#-9.0, c#-10.0, toplevel-statement

I usually set the attribute `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]` to my Program class, as there are no unit tests for this class possible anyways (or don't make sense either), so it doesn't show up as "missing" in the coverage report:

```
[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       // do something awesome
    }
}
```

But with [top-level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/top-level-statements) I don't know how to handle this. It seems not to be possible to set attributes, as I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69962982/1099519

So far, I stick to the classic Class declaration, but maybe they thought about something else, when it comes to unit test code coverage?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since C# 10 the top-level statement generation was changed and now you can add `partial Program` class to the end of top-level statement (or in separate file) and add attribute to it:

```cs
[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
public partial class Program { }
```

Note that in initial feature specification (for C# 9) [states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/top-level-statements#semantics) that the actual names used by compiler are implementation dependent but since C# 10 and NET 6 using partial class is one of the recommended approaches for [unit testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-6.0#project-file-csproj) ASP.NET Core apps which use top-level statements.

But personally I would say that if you need such "advanced" scenarios you should switch back to the "plain old" `Program` classes.

Comment: That feels awful.  What do you do with the other part of the partial that is implied by the use of the `partial` keyword?

Comment: @RobertHarvey what "other part"? The one generated by the compiler which contains all the stuff defined in the top-level statement?

Comment: Well, maybe I'm just too old, but when I used `partial` on a class, there was always another class in your source code with the same name having the `partial` moniker on it.  Otherwise, why bother with `partial`, unless this is just some hacky thing to get around the problem at hand?

Comment: @RobertHarvey If you will not add `patial` to the `Program` class this will not compile due to conflict between `Program` class generated by the compiler and the one which was declared by programmer.

Comment: The last sentence in your post is good advice.  This is a good use case for just using the traditional class declaration.

Comment: Is it possible to add it in a separate file instead of the end of Program.cs ? After all the only purpose of "partial" is to allow splitting the declaration of a class in several files. Declaring it in the same file is awkward.

Comment: @bN_ yes, totally. Just declare partial Program class.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me (.NET 7):

```cs
[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
public static partial class Program { }
```

Looks like the generated `Program` class is static, so putting `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]` on non-static partial `Program` class doesn't apply to top-level code. Not sure why that is, can't find documentation stating that generated `Program` is static.