# How to declare static instance globally in Program.cs of Console App .NET 6.0

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

I have created a console application `.NET 6.0` for learning of Singleton Pattern.
But I have observed a significant change in `Program.cs` file.

`namespace`, `class` and `Main` method have been removed from `program.cs` in `.NET 6.0`.

I believe the code that will be written in `program.cs` will be considered as within `Main` method.
But I want to create two static methods which are using globally intialized instances but I am not able to do that.

By declaring the instances like below:

[image]

It gives Compile Error:

> CS0106 The modifier 'static' is not valid for this item

While using the instances in static methods like below:
[image]

It gives Compile Error:

> CS8421: A static local function cannot contain a reference to
> 'tableservers1'.

Here is all the code of `program.cs` :

```
using SingletonApp;

static TableServers tableservers1 = TableServers.GetInstance();
static TableServers tableservers2 = TableServers.GetInstance();

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Host1();
    Host2();
}
Console.WriteLine();


static void Host1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Host1 Next server is: " + tableservers1.GetNextServer());
}

static void Host2()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Host2 Next server is: " + tableservers2.GetNextServer());
}
```

Please someone can explain how can we use this new minified `program.cs`, specially to use global instance and variables and creating methods.

Comment: As far as I remember you can just readd namespace, class and Main method and work like you normally would

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72013001/2501279) since C# 10 you can achieve this by introducing `public partial class Program` (at the bottom of you top level statement file or in separate file):

```cs
// rest of your top-level statement code 
// ...
public partial class Program 
{
    static TableServers tableservers1 = TableServers.GetInstance();
    static TableServers tableservers2 = TableServers.GetInstance();
}
```

But I would argue that switching to "old style" `Program` class or moving static fields to another class would be a better option.

Comment: Thank you!! I preferred the old style Program and switched back by removing `ImplicitUsings` property from Project File .

Comment: @BaberAliSiddique was glad to help! Though `ImplicitUsings` has nothing to do with top level statements, it is only about importing "default" namespaces for your project type - check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69739444/2501279) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#implicitusings)